# Bluetooth audio problem

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio

I have a rpi zero W with a raspbian lite (without desktop environment). I installed bluetooth support (**bluetooth bluez bluez-utils**),  pulseaudio (**pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-zeroconf alsa-utils avahi-daemon**) and **mpg123**.

I paired a speaker and played some music and it works. But after a few minutes (one, two, ten...) the music stops and if the ssh connection is open the ssh session freezes. 
I tried with nohup, with other speakers, players... but the sound always stopps.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug of the Broadcom/Cypress bluetooth/wifi chip.

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1552, 
https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1402 and more.

There's nothing I can do. I disconnected the on board bluetooth and added a new bluetooth (usb). Now it works.